# R: how to shape two lists of uneven length to a data frame

Tags: r, reshape

I have two lists in R: `a=c(1,3,7)` and `b=c(0,2,4,6,8,10)`. How could I reshape them into a data frame as below:

```
Value type 
0     b
1     a
2     b
3     a
4     b
6     b
7     a
8     b
10    b
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a `name` `list` and then `stack` into a two column `data.frame`

```
stack(list(a = a, b = b))
```

---

Or use `rep` to replicate the object names based on the `length` of the `vector` and then create the `data.frame`

```
data.frame(key = rep(c('a', 'b'), c(length(a), length(b))), value = c(a, b))
```